# Get a variable from object in array

Tags: categories

I'm trying to `echo` `get_the_category($id)[0]->slug` and this works on localhost but not on the server.

The error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['....

Is there a workaround?

Comment: check php versions of local and live server.

Comment: You should do 1 thing per line, whereas you're actually doing 4 things on that line, making it difficult to debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your hosting server has a different and older version of php so this syntax is not supported.

The above syntax is implemented in PHP 5.4.

You have to do it like this:

```
$category = get_the_category($id);
echo $category[0]->slug;
```

**Source:**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45906